Regex pattern for my below mentioned use case
i want to add qutation marks to a position in my string.
At one use case i can´t find a solution.
Input: &LOG Part_Name: vacuum gripper
Output:&LOG Part_Name: "vacuum gripper"

problem use case:
Input: &LOG Part_Name: "blind plug
Output should be: &LOG Part_Name: "blind plug"

My code
string pattern = @"(?<=Part_(Description|Name): )[^\""\s]+";


//example input:&LOG Part_Name: mount
//example output:&LOG Part_Name: "mount"
//example input:&LOG Part_Name: "mount
//example output:&LOG Part_Name: "mount"

Match match = Regex.Match(partDes, pattern);

if (match.Success)
{
    string part = match.Value;
    if (!part.StartsWith("\"") && !part.EndsWith("\""))
        part = "\"" + part + "\"";

    partDes = Regex.Replace(partDes, pattern, part);
}

the correct pattern for both use cases

Try replacing all you code with just Regex.Replace(partDes, @"(Part_(?:Description|Name):\s*)""?([^""]*)""?", "$1\"$2\"")

Are there safe assumptions you can make on the structure of your input strings ? Is it fixed ? Are the words you need to wrap in double quotes always after the last occurrence of a ":" ?

@Veverke
&LOG Part_Name: thats the fix part. After the : the whole context should be between the qutation marks.
For example:
input: &LOG Part_Name: just for demonstration123!
output should be: & LOG Part_Name: "just for demonstration123!"

@usersy: that's why I asked. If this is the case, I think it always better - and much simpler - to solve it without regex.

Given your input has a fixed format, and the strings you want to wrap in double quotes will always come after "&LOG Part_Name:", I really see no reason to use regular expressions.
Why not try something as simple as:
var inputs = new List<string>
{
    "&LOG Part_Name: just for demonstration123",
    "&LOG Part_Name: whatever",
    "&LOG Part_Name:just for demonstration123  ",
    "        &LOG Part_Name: includes pattern, but not at start ",
    "&LOG Part_Name:just for demonstration123 &LOG Part_Name: !last-occurrence! ",
    "Missing parttern just for demonstration123  ",
    string.Empty,
    null
};

var fixedPart = "&LOG Part_Name:";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
        continue;

    var fixedPartLastIndex = input.LastIndexOf(fixedPart);
    if (fixedPartLastIndex < 0)
        continue;

    var outputStr = $"\"{input.Substring(fixedPartLastIndex + fixedPart.Length)?.Trim()}\"";
    Console.WriteLine(outputStr);
}

P.S.: I have assumed you do not care for starting/trailing spaces in the string you need to wrap.
Output:


This is an example in JS, but this regex may work for you: (?<=: )"?([^:]+)$
All this does is look for the last occurrence of :  in the string, then matches an optional quotation mark and captures the rest of the string out to the end, using that capture in the replacement


const testStrings = [
`Input: &LOG Part_Name: vacuum gripper`,
`Input: &LOG Part_Name: "blind plug`
]

output.innerHTML = testStrings.map(str => `
<p>${str}<span style="display: block; color: darkgreen;">${str.replace(/(?<=: )"?([^:]+)$/, '"$1"')}</span></p>
`).join('')
<div id="output"></div>




The matching string starting with " is not part of the requirement.
Also, what happens if there is an additional : after the one in the pattern - like Input: &LOG Part_Name: vvv: dada. Your regex will return only dada.

That's literally the requirement. OP wants to put quotes around the part name and was trying to handle the use case where there's an unmatched opening quote. Also sure, in whatever random scenario you're imagining that could happen, but this is a simple answer to a straightforward issue in a controlled data set

That's one way to see it. I went another way. In any case, I am not the one who downvoted...
